# D3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, radio-button

I'm currently working on creating a force-directed graph using D3.
I have been trying to create an age filter(using an age range) using radio buttons on my HTML page. In addition, I am using my imported JSON file as well.

Scenario:The expected result that I am trying to achieve is when a user selects a radio button, the nodes that have the specific age (created from the JSON file) and meet within the range should come into view while the other nodes are defocused.

So far, an error stating "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined" continuously whenever I click on each of the radio buttons. I did look over my code to see what is wrong with it. However, I do not understand it still. In running the console, the error appears on this particular line of the code, "if(d.age >= ageBracket[0] && d.age <= ageBracket[1])". My guess is that do I have to run another loop for "d.age"?

**Edit: I added more of my JavaScript code and HTML code.

Below contains my code.

1.) Javascript Code:

```
function createGraph() {

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var radius = 25;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

d3.json("patient.json", function(error, d) {

    if (error) throw error;

    var dataset_nodes = d.nodes;
    var dataset_links = d.links;

    // console.log(dataset_nodes);
    //console.log(dataset_links);

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .nodes(dataset_nodes);

    var link_force = d3.forceLink(dataset_links).id(function(d) { return d.id; })
        .distance(function(d) { return d.value; })
        .strength(1);

    var charge_force = d3.forceManyBody()
        .strength(-150); //initial value is 100

    var center_force = d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2);

    simulation
        .force("charge_force", charge_force)
        .force("center_force", center_force)
        .force("links", link_force)



    //add tick instructions: 
    simulation.on("tick", tickActions);

    //add encompassing group for the zoom 
    var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "everything");

    //draw lines for the links 
    var link = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(dataset_links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .style("stroke", "#000000");

    //draw circles for the nodes 
    var node = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataset_nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", radius)
        .attr("fill", "#000000");



    //add drag capabilities  
    var drag_handler = d3.drag()
        .on("start", drag_start)
        .on("drag", drag_drag)
        .on("end", drag_end);

    drag_handler(node);


    //add zoom capabilities 
    var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
        .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

    zoom_handler(svg);



    function drag_start(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    }

    //make sure you can't drag the circle outside the box
    function drag_drag(d) {
        d.fx = d3.event.x;
        d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function drag_end(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
    }

    //Zoom functions 
    function zoom_actions() {
        g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
    }

    function tickActions() {
        //update circle positions each tick of the simulation 
        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

        //update link positions 
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    }



    //Code for radio button filter on age range
    d3.selectAll("input[name=radiob]").on("change", function(d) {



        var age = document.getElementsByName("radiob");
        var ageBracket;


        node.style("opacity", 1);
        link.style("opacity", 1);


        for(var i=0; i < age.length; i++) {

            if(age[i].checked) {

                ageBracket = age[i].value.split("-"); 


                        if(d.age >= ageBracket[0] && d.age <= ageBracket[1])
                    {
                           node.filter(function(d) {
                           return d.age != ageBracket;
                         })
                           .style("opacity", "0.2");

                           link.filter(function(d) {
                           return d.source.age != ageBracket &&
                                  d.target.age != ageBracket;
                  })
                           .style("opacity", "0.2");

                           link.filter(function(d) {
                           return d.source.age == ageBracket ||
                                  d.target.age == ageBracket;
                  })
                            .style("opacity", "1"); 
                    }



            }
        }





    });




}); //End of reading json file


}
```

2.) HTML Code

```
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>D3 Visualization-Force Directed Graph</title>
   <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts2.js"></script>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald"  rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
    <svg width="950" height="820"></svg>


    <script>
      createGraph();
    </script>


    <h3 id="title3">Age</h3>
    <div class="radioButtonBoxMenu">
    <label><input name="radiob" type="radio" value="0-20">0-20</label><br>
    <label><input name="radiob" type="radio" value="20-30">20-30</label><br>
    <label><input name="radiob" type="radio" value="30-40">30-40</label><br>
    <label><input name="radiob" type="radio" value="40">40+</label><br>
    </div>
```

3.) A small portion of the JSON file

```
      "nodes":[

      { "id": "1", "name": "John", "age": "31", "gender": "M"},
      { "id": "2", "name": "Emily", "age": "23", "gender": "F" },
      { "id": "3", "name": "Crystal", "age": "23", "gender": "F" },
      { "id": "4", "name": "Himiko", "age": "23", "gender": "F" }],

     "links": [

      { "source": "hospital1", "target": "1", "value": 200 },
      { "source": "hospital2", "target": "2", "value": 200 },
      { "source": "hospital3", "target": "3", "value": 200 },
      { "source": "hospital4", "target": "4", "value": 200 }]
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code? You don't have to include more of your json, but could you maybe post it in a codepen/jsfiddle? I'll take a look at it then.

Comment: I see. Do you mean for the JavaScript code?

Comment: Yes please, so I can see what variables you're trying to change in the function handling the radio button changed event, and how you populate the data from your json.

Comment: Okay. I just edited my post to include more of the JavaScript code and HTML code.

Comment: where are your `hospitalX` source elements for the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the reason your code wasn't working was because you were treating the array containing your data as the actual nodes. You needed to select the actual svg 'nodes' and 'links' that you had created in the 'createGraph' function. Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxMmvm?editors=0011

To fix this, I selected the 'nodes' and 'links' and then used ['.each'](http://d3indepth.com/selections/) to call a function on each of these objects to check if the data contained an age value within the selected range:

```
//Code for radio button filter on age range
d3.selectAll("input[name=radiob]").on("change", function(d) {
  var self = this;
  var ageBracket = {
    min : self.value.split('-')[0],
    max : self.value.split('-')[1]
  };

  d3.selectAll('.nodes')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .each(function (d) { 
      if (d.age >= ageBracket.min && d.age <= ageBracket.max) {
        d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
      } else {
        d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.2)
      }
    })

  d3.selectAll('.links')
    .selectAll('line')
    .each(function (d) { 
      if (d.target.age >= ageBracket.min && d.target.age <= ageBracket.max) {
        d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
      } else {
        d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.2)
      }
    })
});
```

Note:

- I wasn't entirely sure what the loop in the function handling the
  radio button changed event was doing so I removed it.
- The JSON data in your answer wasn't working so I just used data from
  this bl.ock: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045. I then
  populated it with data relating to age/gender, so you're
  gonna have to swap that back.
- I changed the values in the radiobuttons and added another one 'Any' to fit my code for retrieving the 'ageBracket', check the HTML in the codepen I linked above.

Comment: OH! That actually makes sense now. Thank you @REEE for taking your time and your efforts in this problem. I struggled for days in why my code wasn't working but now I realize it now. :)

Comment: I'm wondering that would the if-else statement would work if a user selected the "40+" radio button?

Comment: Yeah it does work, if you check the HTML in the codepen you'll see I set the value of the 40+ radio button to 40-100. I should have mentioned that in my answer actually but I must have forgotten.

Comment: I see! I must have missed seeing it. Thank you again @REEE :D

Comment: No problem, it was my fault I should have mentioned it in my post. Good luck with the rest of your project :).

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I add a few Hospitals to the json file

```
{
"nodes":[

    { "id": "1", "name": "John", "age": "31", "gender": "M"},
    { "id": "2", "name": "Emily", "age": "23", "gender": "F" },
    { "id": "3", "name": "Crystal", "age": "23", "gender": "F" },
    { "id": "4", "name": "Himiko", "age": "23", "gender": "F" },

    { "id": "hospital1", "name": "H1", "age": "31", "gender": "M"},
    { "id": "hospital2", "name": "H2", "age": "23", "gender": "F" },
    { "id": "hospital3", "name": "H3", "age": "23", "gender": "F" },
    { "id": "hospital4", "name": "H4", "age": "23", "gender": "F" }
],

   "links": [
    { "source": "hospital1", "target": "1", "value": 200 },
    { "source": "hospital2", "target": "2", "value": 200 },
    { "source": "hospital3", "target": "3", "value": 200 },
    { "source": "hospital4", "target": "4", "value": 200 }]
}
```

It was able to draw the nodes and the links.

Then selecting the radio buttons showed a violation an accessing fields from `d`. There is no argument on the radio-button-change callback.
To compare the ages you need to construct an age compare function and use it to update the opacity of the nodes and the links.

```
    d3.selectAll("input[name=radiob]").on("change", function () {
        var age = document.getElementsByName("radiob");
        var ageBracket;
        node.style("opacity", 1);
        link.style("opacity", 1);
        for(var i=0; i < age.length; i++) {
            if(age[i].checked) {
                ageBracket = age[i].value.split("-");
                var testAgeBracket = function (d) { return (d >= ageBracket[0] && d <= ageBracket[1]) };
                node.filter(function(d) { return testAgeBracket(d.age); })
                .style("opacity", "0.2");

                link.filter(function(d) {
                    return !testAgeBracket(d.source.age) &&
                           !testAgeBracket(d.target.age); })
                .style("opacity", "0.2");

                link.filter(function(d) {
                    return testAgeBracket(d.source.age) ||
                           testAgeBracket(d.target.age); })
                .style("opacity", "1"); 
            }
        }
    });
```